# SDL2 draw red lines around a texture

Tags: sdl2

I'd like to debug the SDL_Rect around of my textures visually, what is the best way to draw red lines like an unfilled rectangle around the texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SDL_RenderDrawRect()` function to render an outline around a texture.

```
void Render(void)
{
   SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(pRenderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);

   const SDL_Rect Quad = {TexXPos, TexYPos, TexWidth, TexHeight};

   SDL_RenderDrawRect(pRenderer, &Quad);
}
```